# GCC for MIPS emits assembly label(?) with "= ."

Tags: gcc, assembly, mips

Heyho everyone,

I'm using the GCC 9.3.0 to generate Assembly files for MIPS. When looking at those assembly lines I noticed something that looks like a jump label - but it is never referenced.

```
_ZN10FileSystem8AutoLoad9loadAsyncERKNS0_8FileListE:
    .frame  $sp,40,$31      # vars= 0, regs= 5/0, args= 16, gp= 0
    .mask   0x800f0000,-4
    .fmask  0x00000000,0
    .set    noreorder
    .set    nomacro
    addiu   $sp,$sp,-40
    sw  $18,28($sp)
    lui $18,%hi(_ZN10FileSystemL12curLoadStateE)
    sw  $16,20($sp)
    lw  $16,%lo(_ZN10FileSystemL12curLoadStateE)($18)
    sw  $19,32($sp)
    sw  $17,24($sp)
    lui $19,%hi(_ZN10FileSystem8AutoLoadL14curListElementE)
    move    $17,$4
    li  $4,2            # 0x2
    lw  $3,0($17)
    lw  $2,%lo(_ZN10FileSystem8AutoLoadL14curListElementE)($19)
    bne $16,$4,$L44
    sw  $31,36($sp)

$L36 = .
    addiu   $2,$2,1
$L48:
    sll $4,$2,2
    addu    $3,$3,$4
    lw  $16,0($3)
    sw  $0,%lo(_ZN10FileSystemL12curLoadStateE)($18)
    sw  $2,%lo(_ZN10FileSystem8AutoLoadL14curListElementE)($19)
    sltu    $16,$16,1
$L35:
    lw  $31,36($sp)
    lw  $19,32($sp)
    lw  $18,28($sp)
    lw  $17,24($sp)
    move    $2,$16
    lw  $16,20($sp)
    jr  $31
    addiu   $sp,$sp,40
```

What does "$L36 = ." mean? Is it a jump label that was optimized out?

Comment: `.` is the current position in GAS syntax.  Like `.word .` would emit a word containing its own address.  I'm not sure why GCC wouldn't just emit `$L36:` to define a label at that position, instead of setting the symbol value (address) to that position with `=`.  Do you have some minimal C source that results in asm containing this?

Comment: Sadly, the code has changed by now and this statement is not emitted anymore. However, I think it was related to a goto statement inside the code.

So.... $L36 = . has the same meaning like $L36:? Might this be the result from an optimization step removing this label? Cause it is not referenced anywhere.

Comment: Yes, AFAIK there's no meaningful difference between `$L36:` and `$L36 = .`.  Re: optimization: probably not.  Most optimization happens while the program logic is in an SSA form, then RTL, long before the compiler is actually converting to asm text.

Comment: That is not an optimization, since neither `$L36:` nor `$L36=.` take any code.  `$L36=.` was probably the assembly generated from a label corresponding to a user label in the C unlike than the other labels, which are compiler internal labels that are needed for the if-goto-label assembly form of control structures (if-then/while,return).

Comment: @ErikEidt That would follow with my assumption that it was related to a goto label. But when `$L36:` and `$L36 = .` function the same - why did the compiler not emit `$L36:` directly? Or is it more a thing about pointing out, that this label came from a "goto statement"?

Comment: I would guess that this is the compiler's choice for the assembly generation for this C construct (labeled statement). There is no substantial reason to prefer one form of label over the other.  The generation of the label for the label statement almost certainly goes through a slightly different internal compiler code path than the other labels, so the assembly can be different, and here, well, it is.

Comment: I guess that makes sense! Thank you Peter and Erik!

However... how do I resolve this question now? :'D Should I write a summary and use that to answer? Or does one of you do that?

Comment: @PeterCordes FWIW, pretty much any toy code emits `.Lxx = .` form labels. Here's one: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Kncjs4ddj

Comment: @OfekShilon: Interesting.  It doesn't do that for the auto-numbered labels inside functions like `$L2` (e.g. if we add a loop around printf: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/fxzss4dEM ).  Turning off debug metadata and exception-unwind info with `-g0 -fno-exceptions` gets rid of the labels like `$LFB12 = .` and `$LVL0 = .` that it does define this way, leaving only normal `$L2:`.  Maybe sometimes the compiler internals want to define those labels to a position other than `.`, and it makes the output formatting simpler to just use `= .` instead of a whole different syntax in the normal case.